# horizontal date time picker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I am the beginner in Bootstrap. I have created some web application  for using date picker I need month and date in horizontal but I have created date picker demo it is in picker type but I need this type picker .im search for google , i don't see any tutorial in this type
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AYiq.png)

Comment: for that you have to change css for the datepicker , for display it in horizontal

Comment: sir im try it but not work look this one i need this type,https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AYiq.png

Comment: @chiragsatapara sir, do you know how to change to horizontal??

Comment: i just know that you can do this using a css.

Comment: @chiragsatapara hello sir why not put the correct answer ?

Comment: i have to create new css for this , i have not available.You can try. Your sample image is for the mobile. Follow the web , in web you never ever see the calendar horizontal

Comment: sir, i need for mobile

Comment: i don't know the answer.